# Load pictures from folder into picture box based on date modified

Tags: c#, sorting, picturebox, imagelist

When someone logs into the application is saves a picture of that person into a folder.  On the login form I have 4 picture boxes.  I want the 4 picture boxes to be populated with the last 4 most recent photos based on the last 4 modified dates.  So if there's 10 photos were just sorting by modified and displaying the 4 most recent.

I tried first adding them to a list but wasn't sure how to work with it afterwards to make it do what I wanted

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(PicPath);
    var recentpics = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg*",   SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(t => t.LastWriteTime).ToList();
```

I then tried this which doesn't sort but I wanted to figure out how to display them first, which doesn't work either.

```
string PicPath2 = @"path_to_Pictures";
            string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(PicPath2, "*.jpg");
            PictureBox[] picturebox = new PictureBox[recentpics.Count];
            int y = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
            {
                picturebox[index] = new PictureBox();
                this.Controls.Add(picturebox[index]);
                if (index % 3 == 0) y = y + 10;
                picturebox[index].Location = new Point(index * 120 + 20, y);
                picturebox[index].Size = new Size(100, 120);
                picturebox[index].Image = Image.FromFile(list[index]);
            }
```

Scratching my head now trying to figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: That seems a very indirect and fragile way to track the last 4 users.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you need  most recent, have to sort OrderByDescending, and if only need 4, not load all the list, Take(4)

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(PicPath);
var recentpics = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg*",  SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(t => t.LastWriteTime).Take(4).ToList();
```

second part

```
List<PictureBox> picturebox = List<PictureBox>;
var y = 10;
foreach (var file in recentpics)
{
   var pb = new PictureBox();                
   pb.Location = new Point(picturebox.Count * 120 + 20, y);
   pb.Size = new Size(100, 120);                
   pb.Image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
   this.Controls.Add(pb);
   picturebox.Add(pb);
}
```

this is my full code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(547, 417);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<PictureBox> picturebox = new List<PictureBox>();
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures));
        var recentpics = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(t => t.LastWriteTime).Take(4).ToList();
        var y = 10;
        foreach (var file in recentpics)
        {
            var pb = new PictureBox();                
            pb.Location = new Point(picturebox.Count * 120 + 20, y);
            pb.Size = new Size(100, 120);                
            pb.Image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
            this.Controls.Add(pb);
            picturebox.Add(pb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't display any pictureboxes on the form, which is what I've been running into.  Also getting List<PictureBox>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context when I used what you gave me.

Comment: Forgot to change what had to

Comment: Forgot to change what had to List<PictureBox> picturebox = new List<PictureBox>();  Still getting error on 'file' before I can test it.

Comment: Yes the code have some error, i not have a VS to buid the code, i already fix it and test, it work

Comment: where do you put the code, i alredy tested added it on Form load event

Comment: Sorry, I found that I was doing to break it earlier.  Now if I wanted to use 4 manually added picture boxes on the form instead, is that easy to integrate into this code?

Comment: See I think this will work but I can't seem to set the size of the image.  the picturebox itself is the right size but the image inside the picturebox is blown up.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=PictureBox

Comment: I know, I been doing that, have 15 tabs open reading, I just keep getting errors that all the image size settings are readonly that I can't set them.

Comment: pb.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

Comment: Thanks I eventually found that, I don't use create controls on the fly, is there a way to make it not read only, I want the pictureboxs that were created to be clickable, so for example, if the first picturebox is click, the filename of that picture is used "here" if the second picturebox is clicked the filename of that picture is used "here"

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a=75,b=27;
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\images\52");
    FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.png");
    foreach(FileInfo f in files)
    {
    PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
    p.Location = new Point(a + 137, b);
   p.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName, f.Name));
   p.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 171);
   p.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
   this.Controls.Add(p);
   a += 75;
   p.BringToFront();
  }
 }
```

Perhaps this helps. Its pretty straight forward i think.